# Xcodebuild is not creating an app

Tags: ios, facebook, ios-simulator, xcodebuild

I'm trying to create a simulator app to submit to Facebook for review. I've followed their [instructions to the letter](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/creating-ios-simulator-build-for-review/#generate-simulator), but keep running into problems. I am using CocoaPods and have a workspace instead of a plain old project. Here's the command I'm running:

```
xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator8.1 -workspace [APP].xcworkspace -scheme [APP]
```

I get a `** BUILD SUCCEEDED **` message, but either one of two things will happen:

- No build folder is created, and I can't find where the .App file is.
- A .App is created in a build folder, but is 0 bytes in size and crashes when running with `ios-sim`.

I read that changing the Run scheme to 'Release' might fix it, but that didn't do anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your `[APP]` have a space in it?

Comment: Is the project public?

Comment: 'Fraid not, sad to say.

Answer (score 0):

So, I had the same problem and solved it by doing the following:

I made my app as release build instead of debug in xcode: Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme and then Build Configuration set to Release.

After doing this I then went back to the command line and added a destination for the build:

xcodebuild -arch i386 -sdk iphonesimulator8.1 -workspace [APP].xcworkspace -scheme [APP] **-derivedDataPath /path/to/build**

If you are still having problems make sure you clean and build all of your targets (pods included) and try the above steps again.

Hope this works; it did for me.